# Apk generation fails after the integration of OneSignal in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, onesignal

I have a problem with generating the apk after I integrated the OneSignal.
I think that the code was in Unity and it was converted to Android Studio.

Find the error below and also the link for the onesignal integration I did.
Ps: the apk generation didn't have any problem before the integration of OneSIGNAL

Link : http://www.mediafire.com/file/e57tp7k0rtqq9m3/SuperMaxWorld.rar

ERROR :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForFlavorDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzk$1.class

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/

Your Google Play Services are conflicting.

Do not use `+` as your version number and you need to have all the google play services at the same version

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0
```